# How to use an apex class variable in LWC javascript?

Tags: apex, javascript, lightning-web-components

I have a constants class that has:

`public static final String DATA_TYPE_INTEGER = 'INTEGER';`

I tried to access this in my LWC by doing an import like this:

`import DATA_TYPE_INTEGER from '@salesforce/apex/ConstantsClass.DATA_TYPE_INTEGER';`

But in my Javascript, `.toLowerCase()` is not an operation on DATA_TYPE_INTEGER and I can't seem to get any actual string value from it.

I then tried in my apex class for my LWC:

```
@AuraEnabled
public final String DATA_TYPE_INTEGER = ConstantsClass.DATA_TYPE_INTEGER;
```

And importing that, but got the same issues. I don't think Lightning Components allowed you to access variables like this at all, but was thinking that LWCs might, like they can import custom labels...

Is this actually possible? And if so, how do I go about importing an apex class variable into my javascript?

Comment: What is your use case, why would you need to export a constant from Apex into JS?

Comment: We actually should change the `'INTEGER'` to `Integer.ObjectType` or however we might get that. We do not want hard coded strings thrown around the code, we want them contained and rely on returned Salesforce information (like with Object.SObjectType()) to help with translation. So looking to get the value out of Apex to get the type, or directly get the type from some kind of import LWCs support. Like, can you just directly import type names?

Comment: Writing import does not import the value, it only imports the metadata for calling that method or property.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's no way at least of today to import constant values directly in JS from Apex. The only available way is to [import Apex methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.apex). You can actually utilize this for your use case here.

What you can do is to declare an apex method which returns your constant class `ConstantsClass`, and utilize it on your JS. This will in fact help you to get all the constant values in a single call. Sample below.

**ConstantClass.cls**

```
@AuraEnabled
public final String DATA_TYPE_INTEGER = 'INTEGER';
```

**MyApexController.cls**

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static ConstantClass getAllConstants() {
    return new ConstantClass();
}
```

**JS Controller**

```
import getConstants from '@salesforce/apex/MyApexController.getAllConstants';

...

@wire(getConstants) 
allConstants ({error, data}) {
    if (data) {
        console.log(data.DATA_TYPE_INTEGER ); // will give you the value of your constant
    } else {
        this.error = error;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is fantastic, I never put 1 and 1 together but after seeing it typed out it was obvious we can do this

Comment: @tsalb I thought why not use what's available for this use case :)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but this is a clever way to handle this :). Thank you.

Comment: @TylerDahle Glad that it worked for you :)

Comment: Great!, but does it have side effects on the performance & overall user experience as we are importing a big class (let's say 400 constants) in the client or it'll be just a minor effect @JayantDas